# CSS Font color not changing

Tags: html, css

I am making a php/mysql site and have to make a search panel:

The CSS Code is:

```css
#search {
  color: #c02537;
  width:80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background: rgba(197,101,29,0.6);
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 15px 0 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

#searchf {
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Corresponding HTML is:

```
<div id="search">
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="search" id="searchf">  
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Food Category: <input type="text" name="food_category" id="searchfc"/> </td>
        <td>City: <input type="text" name="city" id="searchfc"/> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
</form>
</div>
```

The CSS fill is applying the margins, padding and border attributes but not the color.

I have no idea why it is not working. Anybody have clues?

Comment: can you post the corresponding HTML please

Comment: Looks correct, are you sure there is no inline style applied? Could you share the relevant `HTML`?

Comment: anyother `!important` rules influence?

Comment: Working here , light red color , right?  Can you please show me links?

Comment: @popnoodles I have added HTML. Now check

Comment: And it's the colour of the words "Food Category:" and "City:" not the input fields that you are having problems with?

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kTF7Y/5/

Comment: do you have any css styles for `#searchf` and `#searchfc` ?

Comment: Be careful if you are looking at placeholder text!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The table's `td` color might be overriding the color property of `#search`.
Try this to specifically color the `td's`

```css
#search table td {
  color: #c02537;
}
```

If you want to change the color of the input elements, try this :

```css
#search table td input {
  color: #c02537;
}
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/anacoc/3/edit)**

Comment: No response as to which element she's having problems with but let's just hope it's the words in the td and that's specific enough to overwrite anything else. Not enough info. Too slow to respond, I'm off!

Comment: @popnoodles Lol, yeah, I went and answered another question till the response came in, which too is not precise, I guess I'll edit the answer if she wants the `input` color

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this?

```css
color: #c02537 !important;
```

Comment: important is not a good thing to use. It should be used very sparingly.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```css
color: #c02537 !Important;
```

If it does not solve your issue then that means this color attribute is overwritten by your default link color.

Use Browser Plugins like Firefox FireBug and verify which CSS styles are applied and which style is overwriting your color.

Hope this helps

Comment: your answer was good before you copied in bad advice about !important.

Comment: Yes thats right but If  Important  will not solve the problem then user can see for the another answer

Comment: Can you tell me Why using an Important is Bad Advice?? I like to know as i m not quite good in CSS  pls

Comment: Please go through this [**link**](http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/) to know about the drawbacks using !important

Comment: You should be able to target your elements without resorting to !important. The C stands for cascading. Using !important stops the whole point of cascading - for someone to overwrite a rule with a another class later on or in a separate CSS file they too have to add !important. It's really bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inheritance in CSS instead of using `!important`:

```css
#search table td {
    color: #c02537;
}
```

Comment: how would that work any better? and we still don't know the HTML!

Comment: the author posted question knows html outer div .

Comment: How would you know that and how would that CSS work any differently?

Comment: yes @JaveriaHabib pls add your html or put your code in [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: @JaveriaHabib you can try it now.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved my personal version of this problem. The symptom was the same as for others here - everything within the brackets was implemented except for the color.

I was able to get it working simply by changing my color value from a hex format to a color-word.

```css
color:#ffa500;
```

to

```css
color:orange;
```

did the trick.

BTW: Had tried the hex color with and without quote signs, didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I had a similar issue and it took some time to resolve it.

This line was not working:

```
lines_with_strong = [re.sub(r'Titel: (.+)', r'<strong style=color: darkblue;>Titel: \1</strong>', line) for line in lines]
```

But this line is:

```
lines_with_strong = [re.sub(r'Titel: (.+)', r'<strong style=color:
darkblue;>Titel: \1</strong>', line) for line in lines]
```

You can barely spot the difference (AI didn't), but in the first one there is a space between color: and darkblue and it had to be removed. So maybe this would also solve the problem of the thread.